# Empty Logs (Though Everything Seems OK)

Tags: rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ 3.5.5 installed on a Windows 2008 R2 server as a Windows service. Everything is as default. The log location is at C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\log and I can see 2 log files:

1. rabbit@HOSTNAME.log
2. rabbit@HOSTNAME-sasl.log

However, they are always empty though RabbitMQ seems to be working fine; i.e., I can log into the web management console, add/delete users, publish/get messages.

Why are the logs empty? What am I missing?

Comment: What version of Erlang have you installed?